# Use GUICE next to GIN

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I'm using successfully GIN on my GWT projet. Now my RPC service will need data from other layer (Business Logic --> Data Access), in the old time I would have done singleton services with needed methods.
Something like 
    MyGwtServiceImpl.getData() --> MyServerSideService.getData() --> MyDaoGetDataFromDB()

But nowadays singleton are not really appreciated and I would like for testing purpose use the injection method.

I know all I need to know is install GUICE for server side, but I'm not really sure where the creation of the injector should be done. Usually it would be done in a main method, but here I'm using GWT.

Will there be conflict between GIN and GUICE lib?

Where should I put the injector creation ?  in the onModuleLoad ? I'm not sure since my application will be divided in several.

Thanks for helping!

---

**Summary :**

- Follow the tutorial given by Thomas (The answer)
- But for injection to work, don't forget to replace (delete in fact) in web.xml :

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.myapp.MyServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/com.myapp/MyService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- By in a Guice module :

  ```
   serve("/com.myapp/MyService").with(MyServiceImpl.class);
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to create your Injector in a `ServletContextListener`. Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule

There's absolutely no conflict between GIN (Guice for GWT, on the client-side) and Guice (on the server-side).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. However I struggled a bit to implement this and make it work.